# IOS, couple UIButtons linked to a single IBAction - lag issue

Tags: ios, xcode, interface

In a single VC app,
a info label is used to display textually the number of clicks of a button,
idea is to toggle the text on even/ uneven number of clicks. I did this ok,
but the problem came when I tried to link couple ( 9 ) UIButtons to the single IBAction where count and label updates happen. Here the label update lags  one step behind the real count ( verified by print(counter) on Console).

May someone help why this happens?
I can do it of course with separate IBAction for each UIButton,
but one action and buttons tags works fine, so it would be nice to keep the code less by single IBAction.

```
import UIKit
```

class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
var player:Player = .cross

@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
 self.label.text = "Player \(player.rawValue) is on the move"

}

@IBAction func Move(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if player == .cross {
        player = .circle
    } else {
        player = .cross
    }
    print(sender.tag)
    print("Player \(player.rawValue) is on the move")
    self.label.text = "Player \(player.rawValue) is on the move"
}

@IBAction func button(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if player == .cross {
        player = .circle
    } else {
        player = .cross
    }
    print(sender.tag)
    print("Player \(player.rawValue) is on the move")
    self.label.text = "Player \(player.rawValue) is on the move"
}
```

}

// the move function is the common IBAction, which lags the label update
// the func button is action for a separate button, doing label updates correctly

// debug progress: similar code worked fine without lag on other desktop,
moreover working code there clean, lags when i run it on my desktop.
I have doubts it might be simulator issue.
For the record, my xcode did it's latest amend few days ago.

Comment: What you're describing should work theoretically. So you're probably doing something wrong. Can you post some code, and screens of how you connected the actions in IB?

Comment: You should add your code if you want to get real help

Comment: sure guys, here is the code. First one UIbutton was right click and dragded into the UIVewController to create IBAction for it, then others were connected to the same via Document Outline tree.

Comment: The code you have shown doesn't have any "count"

Comment: @Pawlw: you are right. What toggles instead of count here is the variable player of type Player, which is emum with only two states - .cross and .circle.